# Not only define action for before_filter but also controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible that i not only define an action for before_filter but also the controller of the action? I want to put the before_filter method into my application_controller but when i define there for example:

```
before_filter :authorize, except: [:index]
```

All controllers are affected that have an index action!
I would like to wirte something like that:

```
before_filter :authorize, except: [user#index]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you are asking for. What you can do is

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authorize
  ...
end


class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:index]
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the before filter in your users_controller?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorize, except: [:index]
  ...
end
```

Comment: But it was my intention to put it into application controller to save time and work